# how apply css file to component JavaSE

Tags: java, css, desktop-application

I am currently developing a **desktop application**.
How I can apply css file to *JavaSE*'s component.

Comment: What GUI toolkit are you using? JavaFX? Swing? SWT?

Comment: I use SWING ,I use eclipse to write code.

Answer (score 1):

Neither Swing itself nor one of its standard Look and Feel supports CSS.

Maybe there is a third party Look and Feel, which provides CSS support, but I'm not aware of such a L&F.

Note that Swing is in maintenance mode and Oracle plans JavaFX to be its successor. JavaFX supports CSS out-of-the-box. If this is a new project, consider to use JavaFX.